# Exclude folder when compiling typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I use Atom to write code. It uses `tsconfig.json` to include and exclude folders. In order to use intellisense I need `node_modules` to be included, but when I want to compile it to `js` I don't want `node_modules` to be compiled. 
So I need to call `tsc` in the upper folder where the `config.ts` is, and this results in compiling the whole `node_modules`.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
node_modules
config.ts
spec
  |--test1.ts
  |--test2.ts
```

Any idea how to exclude `node_modules` when compiling with `tsc` command?

Comment: It doesn't make sense if you skip the node_modules where pre-defined dependencies were sitting on? If you wat o do it forecefully then nan you elaborate the scenario?

Answer (score 47):

Use exclude property

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    }
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

> Files included using "include" can be filtered using the "exclude" property. However, files included explicitly using the "files" property are always included regardless of "exclude". The "exclude" property defaults to excluding the node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages and  directories when not specified.

link updated:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude

Comment: Whenever I'm adding `"exclude":["node_modules"]` I get errors in my `.ts` files because atom typescript cannot find modules in `node_modules`.

Comment: It will work for node_modules but when you exclude your tests then IDE will stop support their types and mark most of them as "red". What's ideal is to exclude the tests upon the build with the command line without being forced to create a separate tsconfig.prod.json - therefore `--excludeFiles` from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html might be the best solution.